# Conectar programa JAVA con VM de Google Cloud

Tags: java, mysql, google-cloud-platform, vps, mysqlconnector

Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Antes de aventurarme a comprar un VPS para realizar las pruebas de mi proyecto decidí intentar realizar la conexión con una VM de Google Cloud en la que corre un SO Ubuntu con los servicios de apache y mysql. Cabe destacar que he realizado la prueba remotamente antes con una VM en mi computador personal con el mismo SO en la misma versión y todo funcionaba correctamente, pero en este caso no me está conectando con el programa.

Ya modifiqué la IP en la ruta /ect/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf por la IP interna de la maquina o 0.0.0.0 pero no me ha funcionado. Es la primera vez que uso un servicio de VPS y solo me está dando ese error. Si alguien me puede ayudar estaría inmensamente agradecido.

PD: si me deja acceder a través de la IP pública de la maquina /phpmyadmin a la base de datos pero no me deja acceder con ninguna herramienta de administracion de base de datos, he usado MySQL Workbench y SQLYog de bd y estoy usando actualmente el driver mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar para la conexión.

Espero haber explicado bien mi situación.

Comment: puedes compartir las firewall rules que tienes aplicando a esa máquina virtual?, por defecto todas las conecciones entrantes son rechazadas en las VMs de GCP a menos que una regla las permita, revisa que el puerto en el que corre la base de datos en la máquina virtual acepte connecciones de acuerdo a las firebase rules

Comment: @SoniSol Es correcto, había olvidado por completo el firewall. En cuanto vi esto abrí de una vez la configuración de firewall y apliqué nueva regla. Ya el programa está funcionando correctamente.

Muchas gracias por su aporte <3.